# Getting payment outside of platform

Tags: freelance-websites, payment-terms

If a client and freelancer agrees to pay outside of platform directly i don't see a problem.

But some sites just block the accounts ( they spy on your messages yeah).

Can anyone explain me how is this even right ?

I know its in their "ToC" but that's just not right.

You want to make money you make by ads, reddit, craiglist doesn't ask for fees does it ?

Comment: Did you really have to ask this? Was it really not clear? If I connect you and a client where you will earn $10k, don't you think I deserve to take finder's fee?!

Comment: nah man you dont. its like the tinder's ceo will come and say  "hey i deserve a handjob as finder's fee" @PeterMV

Comment: You still have to learn a lot about business. BTW. can you give you your email so that I can see if you can find some clients for me? As I am safe from you asking for finders fee, I would gladly use your time and services to get new clients for my business.

Comment: @PeterMV slimshadybriandeadlikejimbrady@gmail.com

Comment: Lol, using a platform to get projects that you make money on, and then complain that the platform takes a %. It's right because you decided to use that platform. Don't like the %? Don't use the platform. Every single middle man service in the world takes a %, this is no different.

Answer (score 4):

1. **This is how business is done**. If an agent connects you with a source
   of income, it is *customary* for that agent to be compensated for
   making the connection and in turn helping you earn money. How much that "agent" receives should be explained prior to any connections being made. While I don't use crowd source web sites for work, even I know they all detail their fees prior to signing up for their services (which is why I don't use them).
2. If you disagree with the Terms of Service (TOS) if **any** web site
   or service you are *free to not use that service*. Using the service
   in any respect implies agreement to their terms.
3. Focusing on fees associated with receiving payments will ultimately
   be frustrating and annoying in almost all cases. Sure a crowd source site may take 10%. However, PayPal and credit card processors will take a percentage as well were you to use them. There's no such thing as *legally* receiving money for work performed *without* paying a fee somewhere. If you *don't* pay a fee, then you are most likely breaking tax laws by not reporting the income and trying to pass it off as "friends and family" money. That may work up to a point, but once you start earning decent money it has a high probability of raising eyebrows with tax auditors.

It's understandable to dislike the fees associated with some services and really, it's a pretty natural reaction when starting out. However, if you gain enough experience to realize that you'd be making $0 if you were *not* using the payment processor or agent, you quickly realize the percentages are merely the cost of doing business. I don't know about you, but I would honestly prefer to make $10,000 and have to pay someone $1,000, resulting in my net profit of $9,000, than make $0 because I'm not willing to pay any percentage.